# How to detect Infinity values in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Scala has `Double.isNaN` for detecting not-a-number but no `Double.isInf` for detecting (positive or negative) infinity.

Why? I'd like to check whether a parameter is a "real" number (i.e. has a numeric value). Converting it to a string and checking for "inf" or something will do it, but there must be a better way?

Like in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf

Using Scala 2.10

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Scala's [`Double`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Double) has an `isInfinite` method, and `Neg`/`Pos` variants:

```
scala> val a = 22.0
a: Double = 22.0

scala> a.isInfinite
res0: Boolean = false

scala> val b = 2.0/0
b: Double = Infinity

scala> b.isInfinite
res1: Boolean = true

scala> b.isPosInfinity
res4: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed it.

Comment: @akauppi Maybe because the REPL doesn't autocomplete it. I see eclipse will offer it.

Comment: @som-snytt oh, good point. IDEA does show them. (I think the Netbeans plugin too)

Answer (score 4):

What everyone else has said, plus this: the reason for the separate `isNaN` is that comparison with `NaN` is special:

```
scala> val bar = Double.NaN
bar: Double = NaN

scala> bar == Double.NaN
res0: Boolean = false
```

No such rules apply for infinity, so there is no need for a special check function (except for the convenience of handling the sign):

```
scala> val foo: Double = Double.PositiveInfinity
foo: Double = Infinity

scala> foo == Double.PositiveInfinity
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thanks. What I find slightly confusing is that Double.PositiveInfinity uses the (too) long wording, whereas Double.isPosInfinity uses a shorter one.

Answer (score 1):

The method actually is there. It's just called `isInfinity` instead of `isInf`.

See scaladocs for `RichDouble` line 36: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/runtime/RichDouble.scala#L36